# Go: How to spawn a bash shell

Tags: go

I'm looking to do something in Go where I launch the user into another shell on login. So this go app will do some work on login and then drop the user in a bash shell and then on exit do more work then quit. I can't seem to get it into a shell.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    proc := exec.Command("/bin/bash")
    out, e := proc.StdoutPipe()
    proc.Start()
    fmt.Println("Ran a shell in go")

    fmt.Println(out)
    fmt.Println(e)
}
```

That just exits right away.

Comment: I must admit, I don't fully understand the problem. You need a new shell, in the shell?

If I understand correctly, something like the following might help:

`syscall.Exec(os.Getenv("SHELL"), []string{os.Getenv("SHELL")}, syscall.Environ())`

Answer (score 2):

Go figure.. figure it out after I post but here's what worked

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    shell := exec.Command("/bin/bash")
    shell.Stdout = os.Stdout
    shell.Stdin = os.Stdin
    shell.Stderr = os.Stderr
    shell.Run()
    fmt.Println("Ran a shell in go")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I must admit, I don't fully understand the problem. You need a new shell, in the shell?

If I understand correctly, something like the following might help:

`syscall.Exec(os.Getenv("SHELL"), []string{os.Getenv("SHELL")}, syscall.Environ())`

Comment: `Exec()` is *replacing* the Go process with a shell. That's not usually what folks mean when they say they want to run a program.