# Using Go to spawn a shell with a TTY from "nc -e /bin/bash"

Tags: bash, shell, go

I want to escape a restricted shell spawning a bash shell via Go. In other words, I want to do this but using Go:

```
python -c 'import pty; pty.spawn("/bin/bash")'
```

I am totally new to Go. I have tried this (following the answer in this question [Go: How to spawn a bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485656/go-how-to-spawn-a-bash-shell)) but nothing happens:

```
package main

import "os"
import "os/exec"

func main() {
    shell := exec.Command("/bin/bash")
    shell.Stdout = os.Stdout
    shell.Stdin = os.Stdin
    shell.Stderr = os.Stderr
    shell.Run()
}
```

Also if I add the  `fmt.Println("hello")` line at the end of the main function nothing is printed

**UPDATE**

Maybe I did not expalined well. What I am trying to achieve it's to spawn a shell gotten a restricted shell. This is what I did:
Listener:

```
nc.traditional -l -p 8080 -e /bin/bash
```

Connects to listener:  And I exec the code here

```
nc.traditional localhost 8080 -v
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program works fine for me.  I put some error checking in and an extra print statement which should make what is happening clearer.  You are getting an interactive shell, it just looks **exactly** like your previous shell.

```
$ go run Go/shell.go 
$ # whoa another shell
$ exit
exit
exiting
$ # back again
$
```

Here is the revised program

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    shell := exec.Command("/bin/bash")
    shell.Stdout = os.Stdout
    shell.Stdin = os.Stdin
    shell.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := shell.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("command failed: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("exiting\n")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated the question. Indeed if I do all this from a tty shell it works but it's not the case. I apologise If I did not explain well